# I am new to node js how to get dependent dynamic dropdown from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cascadingdropdown

my node code:

```
app.get('/block_name', function (req,res){

var sql='SELECT  `block_name`,`block_id` FROM `tbl_block`  ';
connection.query(sql,function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json(result);
});
```

});

`app.get('/site_name', function (req,res){`

```
var sql='SELECT  `site_name`,`site_id` FROM `tbl_site` ';
connection.query(sql,function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json(result);
});
```

});

HTML

Site

```
      <select name="site" id="dropdown" >
        <option value="">- select -</option>
      </select>
     <label class="field" >Block</label>
      <select name="block" id="dropdown1" >
        <option value="">- select -</option>
      </select>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "/site_name",
        type : "GET",
        success : function(data){

            var len = data.length;

            console.log(data);
            $("#dropdown").empty();
            for(var i =0; i<len;i++){
            var value1 = data[i]['site_name'];
            var value2 = data[i]['site_id'];
                $("#dropdown").append("<option value='"+value2+"' >"+value1+"</option>");

            }

        }
    });
}); 

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "/block_name",
        type : "GET",
        success : function(data){

            var len = data.length;

            console.log(data);
            $("#dropdown1").empty();
            for(var i =0; i<len;i++){
            var value1 = data[i]['block_name'];
            var value2 = data[i]['block_id'];
                $("#dropdown1").append("<option value='"+value2+"' >"+value1+"</option>");

            }

        }
    });
}); 


 </script>
```

my second dropdown lists all the data but i need particular thing to be listed according to the first dropdown.
Thanks in advance..
Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1):

Anytime the first drop-down changes value, you need to repopulate the second drop-down based on the select value in the first drop-down - usually by rerunning your ajax call to load the second drop-down, but using the value of the first drop-down to decide which data to request from the server.

You would do this by installing an event handler on the first drop-down so you can detect any time its value is changed and then you would repopulate the second dropdown with a fresh ajax call whenever that event on the first drop-down occurs.

Comment: Pls give it with some examples @jfriend00

Comment: @HameedIrfan - Examples of what?  What do you need help with?  Do you know how to make an event handler to see when the 1st drop-down changed?  That's where you would repopulate the 2nd drop-down.

Comment: yes , using onchange event i can select the second dropdown . but how to repopulate the second dropdown with fresh ajax because in ajax i give an url to call that query @jfriend00

Comment: @HameedIrfan - You need to specify an ajax URL that will get you the blocks that you want to show for the currently selected site.  I don't know how your server URLs work to know what to suggest since you haven't disclosed any of that.  Do you have the ability to fetch blocks for a specific site? If I understand your question, that's what you want to do.