# Loop through array field in schema mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

so i have a Community schema that contains name and departments, the departments field has a type array ..how to do i render the departments in a dropdownlist dependent on the name field.

**this is my routes.js**

```
router.get('/setup', (req, res,next) => { 

  Community.find(function(err, data) {
    res.render('setup', {
        community: data,

    });
});
});
```

**this is my Community schema**

```
const CommunitySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  department: [{
    type: String
  }]
    
});
```

**and this is my setup.ejs**

```
 <label for="fullname"><strong>What department do you belong to ?</strong></label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="community" name="community">
                     <optgroup label="Select Table">
                     <% community.forEach(function (practice) { %>
                       
                     <option >  <%= practice.department.pop() %>   </option>  
                     <% }) %>>
                     </optgroup>
                    </select>
```

**this is the data **

```
{
"name":"Engineering",
"departments":[ "Electrical engineering", "Mechanical engineering", "Chemical engineering" ]
},
{
"name":"Arts",
"departments":[ "Philosophy", "Theatre arts", "English" ]
}
```

i am trying to make a dependent dropdownlist , i hope my question was understood

Comment: Can you also add how your data is structured in after `find` query.....just `console.log(data)` and add sample data here if its possible

Comment: @RohitAmbre i have added the sample data. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not perform `pop` operation on your array,

Try this way, code might give syntactical errors but idea is that you should loop over your `departments` array to create options inside `select` element.

```html
<label for="fullname"><strong>What department do you belong to ?</strong></label>
<select class="form-control" id="community" name="community">
    <optgroup label="Select Table">
        <% community.forEach(function (practice) { %>
            <% practice.departments.forEach(function (dept) { %>
                <option>  <%= dept %>   </option>
            <% }) %>> 
        <% }) %>>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

.

(my assumption below)

I'm not sure about what is the expected output in your question but I think your expecting something like below in your select dropdown, if yes, then above code wont give the result.

```
|- Engineering
|--- Electrical engineering
|--- Mechanical engineering
|--- Chemical engineering
|- Arts
|--- Philosophy
|--- Theatre arts
|--- English
```

use following

```html
<label for="fullname"><strong>What department do you belong to ?</strong></label>
<select class="form-control" id="community" name="community">
    <% community.forEach(function (practice) { %>
        <optgroup label="<%= practice.name %>">
            <% practice.departments.forEach(function (dept) { %>
                <option>  <%= dept %>   </option>
            <% }) %>> 
        </optgroup>
    <% }) %>>
</select>
```

Comment: great it works .. but i want to make 2 dropdownlists , one for the community and the other for the departments.. the departments dropdownlist should depend on the value of  the community

Comment: for doing that you'll have to change implementation of your code. instead passing data from route to template file, make an AJAX call to get list for 1st dropdown then `onChange` of 1st dropdown make another AJAX call to get dependant dropdown list. You will have make 2 APIs returning JSON. for example check this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45750400/11389012)